# Can't use scipy stats function on nested list

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, nested-lists

I've been trying to scipy.mstats.zscore a dataset that is intentionally organized into a nested list, and it gives:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'long'
```

which probably suggests that scipy.stats doesn't work for nested lists.

What can I do about it? Does a `for` loop affect the nature of the zscore when applied to the dataset in a "subset" way?

e.g.

```
dataset = [[1.5,3.3,2.6,5.8],[1.5,3.2,5.6,1.8],[2.5,3.1,3.6,5.2]]
zscore_dataset = zscore(dataset)
```

vs

```
zscore_dataset = []
for zscore_list in zscore_dataset,
    list = zscore(zscore_list)
    zscore_dataset.append(zscore_dataset)
```

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Can't a beginner be unsure of this? There wasn't anything on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply it on a [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) reflecting the nested lists.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array([[1.5,3.3,2.6,5.8],[1.5,3.2,5.6,1.8],[2.5,3.1,3.6,5.2]])
stats.mstats.zscore(dataset)
```

works fine.